# Multiple socket clients

Tags: javascript, sockets, connection

i try to create multiples clients of socket.io and each one connected to a different server, but so far secound server is get refused connection and the first one is get disconnect i think because when i leave only one clinet in array everythink is ok.

Message with two clients

```
Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:10002
```

```html
function connections() {
    var data = {
    "clients": [{
        "10000": "127.0.0.1",
    },
{
        "10002": "127.0.0.1",
    }]
};

data.clients.forEach(function(client_port, index) {
    console.log(client_port + index);
    Object.keys(client_port).forEach(function(client_ip) {    
        console.log(client_ip + " = " + client_port[client_ip]);
        var port = client_ip;
        var ip = client_port[client_ip];
        socket = net.connect(port, ip, function () {
            socket.on('data', function (data) {
                var dataHex = data.toString('hex');
                var dataString = data.toString('utf8');
                util.log('get data:' + dataString);
                $('response').value += dataString;
                arrayparadox = dataString.split(' ');
                console.log(arrayparadox[1]);
            });
                util.log('connected to server ' + client_ip + ':' + client_port);
            });
    });
});
    }
```

use if i leave only one client in array everythink is okai.

Comment: Have you tried setting up CORS, or turning your firewall off?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're not declaring socket inside your loop, so maybe it's getting overwritten?  Try putting var in front of socket  = net.connect...

Comment: ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server while connecting - but CORS  should not apply (https://blog.securityevaluators.com/websockets-not-bound-by-cors-does-this-mean-2e7819374acc). Any information on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your code.

1. In JSON object keys are not in order of insertion. So you can't claim which one is connected first or second since there is no order.
2. What you are doing is using same variable `socket` for all of your socket. So chances are there that in second iteration the `socket` object is getting updated and previous one is garbage collected. What you can do is to create an array of socket objects :

   `socket[index++] = net.connect();`
3. Now you can attach events like `socket[index].on(data,function(){})`